# CSS transistions

Tags: css, animation, input

I am making a table in CSS that will have some interesting animations on it. When clicking on the text field, it should expand, but in addition to this, it should make the button to the side of it move as well. Can anyone see an easy way of doing this? I've included the code here:

```html
<html> <head> <title></title>
<style>
.input1 {
 width: 30%;
 padding: 5px 5px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
 -webkit-transition: width 0.35s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
 width: 45%;
 button.width:50%;
}
.button {
 background-color: #34B0D9;
 radius: 12px;
 color: white;
 padding: 12px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-family: calibri;
 font-size: 85%;
}
</style>

<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<table id="scoreboard" width="1000" style="border:1px solid #000000; z-index:5; position:absolute; left:250px; background-color: white;">
 <tr>
  <td style="font-size:180%; font-family:calibri black; padding-left:15px; padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px">Scoreboard</h1></td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr style="background-color:#E8E8E8">
  <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px">Enemy boats found:</td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px">Enemy tiles checked:</td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr style="background-color:#E8E8E8">
  <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px">Boats lost:</td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px">Time taken:</td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr style="background-color:#E8E8E8">
  <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px">Result:</td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td style="padding-left:18px; padding-top:30px;"><input type="text" class="input1" placeholder="Enter name here..."></input></td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td style="padding-left:330px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:10px"><button class="button" style="padding: 8px">Submit score</button></td>
 </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can make the button go after the input (so that they are both siblings) you can use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors): `~`. The part you'd be interested in is:

```
input[type="text"]:focus ~ .button {
    /* Your styles here */
}
```

This effectively selects: a `.button` that comes after a text field which is focused, and works as long as they're siblings (i.e. they are contained within the same element). So you can't have them wrapped in separate `<td>` tags.

This is of course, a pure CSS solution, so if they *do* have to be wrapped in separate tags, you'll need to use JS.

```css
.input1 {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.35s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  width: 45%;
}
input[type=text]:focus + .button {
  /* Whatever you want the button to do when the preceding input is focused */
  min-width: 50%;
  /* Note: we use min-width rather than width, as you can't transition `width:auto` */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.button {
  background-color: #34B0D9;
  radius: 12px;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 85%;
  min-width: 0;
  /* Note: we use min-width rather than width, as you can't transition `width:auto` */
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>

  <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <table id="scoreboard" width="1000" style="border:1px solid #000000; z-index:5; position:absolute; left:250px; background-color: white;">
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size:180%; font-family:calibri black; padding-left:15px; padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px">Scoreboard</h1>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="background-color:#E8E8E8">
      <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px">Enemy boats found:</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px">Enemy tiles checked:</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="background-color:#E8E8E8">
      <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px">Boats lost:</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px">Time taken:</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="background-color:#E8E8E8">
      <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px">Result:</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left:18px; padding-top:30px; display:block">
        <input type="text" class="input1" placeholder="Enter name here..."></input>
        <button class="button">Submit score</button>
      </td>
    </tr>


  </table>

</body>

</html>
```